# How to pass a value from one page to another in MEAN?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

Angular View Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="edit(obj._id)">Edit</button>
```

Angular Controller code:

```
$scope.edit=function(id) {
    console.log('edit() called........');
    console.log(id);
    $http.get('/findEmp/',$scope.e).success(function(response) {
        $scope.e = response; 
    });
}
```

Node Js server code:

```
app.get('/findEmp/:id',empCtrl.findEmp1);
```

Node controller code:

```
module.exports.findEmp=function(req,res){
    var id=req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    emp.find({'_id':id},function(err,results){
        console.log('result: '+results);
        res.json(results);
    });
}
```

I am not able to redirect a page to another page with this code.

I am trying ... pass a object to angular controller which will send to a node controller and node controller will find and sent a respond, with this response i want to redirect my page for edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with $location service:

```
$location.path( "/findEmp" );
```

And if path depends on some response data:

```
$location.path( "/findEmp/" + response.id );
```

**Edit:**
The 404 problem is probably because url should be "/findEmp/" + id.

You can preserve data between pages with simple getter/setter factory. Something like this:

```
services.factory('someFactory', function () {
    var data;
    return {
        set: function (d) { data = d; },
        get: function () { return data; }
    };
});
```

Comment: I have updated answer, check if response has id property, maybe there is _id or something? Can you write what is output of response?

Comment: Actually the problem is here: $http.get('/findEmp/',$scope.e)
There is no url for "/findEmp/", so you should put id there. You can save data that you fetched from server in service, or you can fetch it after you change page.